# Breaking up an ES6 class into multiple files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

With a JavaScript 'class' (not really a class, I know), it's possible to break up a big definition by putting methods in separate files, like this:

```
var Foo = function () {
  console.log('initializing foo');
};

Foo.prototype.render = require('./render');
```

But with ES6 classes, it looks like the syntax rules out this approach – it seems the methods always have to be written as function literals inside the class block.

I [tried this](https://6to5.org/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('initializing%20foo')%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20require('.%2Frender')%3B%0A%7D%0A) in the 6to5 REPL:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initializing foo');
  }

  require('./render');
}
```

...but it errors.

As an example, CoffeeScript's class syntax allows me to do this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    console.log 'initializing foo'

  render: require './render'
```

Is there really no way to do this with ES6 classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classes are just syntactic sugar. So you can do

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initializing foo');
  }
}

Foo.prototype.render = require('./render');
```

Or you could create a getter:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initializing foo');
  }

  get render() {
    return require('./render');
  }
}
```

Comment: What about accessing `this` within those methods?

Comment: @NathanH: what about it? Except for arrow functions, the value of `this` depends on how a function a function is *called*, not how it was created.

Comment: Thanks I think that was it, I was probably using the arrow syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    console.log('initializing foo');
  }

  render() { 
    require('./render'); 
  }
}
```